# sequence diagrams in #ballerina

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-composer

It seems that Composer is the only tool that will allow to set up structure in a ballerina program allowing you to create and edit high level logic. VScode seems to have a display function of a sequence diagram and i have not seen any sequence diagram support in IntelliJ.

What are the plans as to the support of at least the view of a diagram and/or creation of sequence diagrams as a quick way to set up code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about future development plans are not within the scope of stackoverflow.

Comment: Please create an issue requesting for new features: https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues Use stackoverflow for usage related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am from the ballerina tooling team.

Currently the plan is to support following features across all the IDE plugins including Composer, VSCode and Idea plugin for the July 2018 release.

- Language Support - ( Syntax highlighting and LS features. )
- Run and Debug
- Visualizing the ballerina programs with sequence diagrams.

And Ballerina Composer will ship with following additional features targeting integration development.

- Graphically design integrations.
- Design first REST API development.
- Integrated Try It Client.
- Development time HTTP Tracing Support.

Eventually, we would want to bring all the Composer features into other plugins. Hope above helps.

**Edit:** Please use [ballerina dev list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ballerina-dev) to discuss/question about features supported and future plans.

Comment: Would you please help to keep the site clean and direct the user to the correct place to ask this off-topic question instead of answering it....

Comment: @piet.t Yes that makes sense, Ideal place to ask this question is the ballerina dev list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ballerina-dev